# error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): eks v1.22

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
annotations:
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-1:0987654322:certificate/ee21bffb-ba4a-45a6-95a6-00551c1cfa32"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: "15"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: "5"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: "2"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: "[{"HTTPS":443}, {"HTTP":80}]"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-1-2017-01
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: "stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=60"
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: "2"
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
name: alb-alb
namespace: deploy
spec:
rules:
-
http:
paths:
-
backend:
serviceName: service-svc
servicePort: 80
path: /*

---

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
  ...
  name: alb-alb
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-svc
            port:  # <-- Correction to your spec starts here
              number: 80
```